# Mysql query doesn't give any result with Group By on date

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I am creating a booking diary where I need to display customer information, booking status and description on the booking diary. Database is like

```
id | BookingRef | CusotmerName | Status | InDate | InTime | BookingDate | Details |
```

I want to display information in Ascending order of time but need to Groupby it on Date.
For example, if the record is like

```
id | BookingRef | CusotmerName | Status | InDate | InTime | BookingDate | Details |
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
1 | 4656AB | John Smith | Open | 17-03-2019 | 08:30 | 16-03-2019 14:30 | Want to check my glasses    
2 | 4554AB | Rick Ronald | Open | 17-03-2019 |08:55 | 16-03-2019 14:30 | Want to check my glasses    
3 | 4434AB | Serra Willa | Open | 17-03-2019 |10:05 | 16-03-2019 14:30 | Want to check my glasses    
4 | 4954AB | Jay Banker | Open | 18-03-2019 |09:25 | 16-03-2019 14:30 | Want to check my glasses    
5 | 4154AB | Damien Baker | Open | 19-03-2019 |11:55 | 16-03-2019 14:30 | Want to check my glasses
```

These data should display like

```
17-03-2019    
John Smith | 08:30 | Want to check my glasses | Open    
Rick Ronald |08:55 | Want to check my glasses | Open    
Serra Willa |10:05 | Want to check my glasses | Open    
18-03-2019
Jay Banker | 09:25 | Want to check my glasses | Open    
19-03-2019    
Damien Baker |11:55 | Want to check my glasses | Open
```

My query this pulls out data but I need to group it with InDate so I used:

```
select *
from appointments ASC InDate;
```

This generate below error:

```
select *
from appointments
GROUP BY InDate;
```

error:

> mysqli_query(): (42000/1055): Expression #1 of SELECT list is not in
>   GROUP BY clause and contains nonaggregated column
>   'appdb.appointments.id' which is not functionally dependent on columns
>   in GROUP BY clause; this is incompatible with
>   sql_mode=only_full_group_by

Is there any suggestion, how can I achieve what I want as a result?

Comment: You're confusing data retrieval with data display, the latter being best handled in application code

Comment: My writing query is not strong but I think I need self join or something to get this result, can you point me in the right direction? Thanks for looking into this question.

Comment: See previous comment. :-(

Comment: You mix up the group by of sql with grouping in report generation. You just need an order by InDate and do the grouping by program or some reporting tool.

Comment: Thanks @Strawberry, I did manage it with order by on date and time. Appreciate to point me in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

This is too long for a comment.

A SQL result set -- like a SQL table -- consists of columns and rows.  *Every row has the same set of columns.*  This is a very important principle when working with SQL.

Your desired result set seems to have two types of rows.  One with a single date and another with a bunch of columns.  Structured like that, you cannot return this with SQL.  It is simply outside the boundaries of what the language does.  Say, like using Python to clean your bathroom.

You *could* come close by converting each row to a single string or by putting the date in the `CustomerName` column and leaving the rest of the columns empty.  However, those are really hacks.  And the better way to get data in the format you want is to do it at the application layer.